# cannot load the message properly on angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.3"                src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>This is the message {{message}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my script file has

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hi this is great ";
};
```

but still the result is showing {{message}} and not the actual message

Comment: can you post a fiddle for your code

Comment: If this is all your code, you are really missing necessary parts including: creating an app and registering the controller.

Comment: where is your ng-app?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>This is the message {{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      Hello, {{message}}!
    </div>
</body>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hi this is great ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/1c12r4hr/1/

Comment: for some reason the script that direct to angular is doing something wrong, try changing it to:     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: This is a working plunker with angular 1.4: http://plnkr.co/edit/nYe7O1WCM7paK5pV8omd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script>
            document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>This is the message {{message}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And script.js

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hi this is great ";
});
```

Working example [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2)